# How to fix SQL syntax error with Laravel?

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel-5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cctjn.png)I make controller about input data Combobox, and I input data appear SQL syntax error. how to fix the error?

I have tried to fix, name of column database is id_makanan, file, nama_makanan, kode jenis, created_at, updated_at. but in error said

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'makanan' in
>   'field list' (SQL: insert into `makanan` (`file`, `makanan`, `jenis`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1568873326_272484-P5VPQM-122.jpg,
>   Burger, 3, 2019-09-19 06:08:46, 2019-09-19 06:08:46))

In controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Gambar;
use App\JenisMkn;
use App\cmb;
use Input;
//use File;

class MakananController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $makanan = Gambar::all();
        return view('makanan', ['makanan'=>$makanan]);
    }
    public function input()
    {
        $jenis = JenisMkn::select('id_jenis','jenis_makanan')->get();
        return view('upload_gambar',['jenis'=>$jenis]);
    }
    public function proses(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'file'=>'required|file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
            'makanan'=>'required',
            'jenis'=>'required',
        ]);

        $file = $request->file('file');
        $nama_file = time()."_".$file->getClientOriginalName();

        //nama folder tempat file diupload
        $tujuan_upload = 'image_file';
        $file->move($tujuan_upload,$nama_file);

        Gambar::create([
            'file' =>$nama_file,
            'makanan'=>$request->makanan,
            'jenis'=>$request->jenis,
        ]);
        return redirect('/makanan');
    }
}
```

Comment: show your table screenshot.

Comment: show us your table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Controller,

```
Gambar::create([
    'file' =>$nama_file,
    'nama_makanan'=>$request->makanan,
    'kode_jenis'=>$request->jenis,
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

just rename `makanan` to `nama_makanan` in create statement.

```
Gambar::create([
    'file' =>$nama_file,
    'nama_makanan'=>$request->makanan,
    'jenis'=>$request->jenis,
]);
```

Comment: yes but in column nama_makanan change like this "?"   this is new error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'makanan' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `makanan` (`file`, `makanan`, `jenis`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1568875958_Screenshot (692).png, ?, 3, 2019-09-19 06:52:38, 2019-09-19 06:52:38))

Comment: Hm, i focused on `makanan`, so i did not see that there is an other mistyped column-name. The accepted answer with `kode_jenis` is correct, for sure. BTW, in my mind its not too hard to understand a message like `Unknown column 'makanan' `...